# How to implement a reliable, generalized and type safe function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, functional-programming

I have an `Object` that may occur in three different forms:

```
{done, key, value}
{done, key}
{done, value}
```

I pass two of these `Object` to a function that needs to handle all three cases similar to a logical `or` operation.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
const orFun = (pred, def) => x => y => {
  const r = pred(x),
    s = pred(y);

  return !r && !s ? def
    : r && s ? [x, y]
    : r ? x
    : y;
};

const entry = {key: 1, value: "a"};
const value = {value: "a"};
const key = {key: 1};

orFun(x => x !== undefined, []) (entry.key) (entry.value); // ["a",1]
orFun(x => x !== undefined, []) (key.key) (key.value); // 1
orFun(x => x !== undefined, []) (value.key) (value.value); // "a"
orFun(x => x !== undefined, []) (none.key) (none.value); // []
```

This works for my specific problem but I wonder if this also applies to other use cases. Is this a generalized solution and type safe in the spirit of functional programming?

Comment: Your question is opinion-based, though quite interesting. On it!

Comment: "*Is this a generalized solution*" - I'm not even sure what the actual problem is here that you are trying to solve. Are you saying that you always want to pass the `.key` and `.value` of any of these objects? And what (why) are you trying to generalise this?

Comment: "*Is this type safe in the spirit of functional programming?*" - it's really unclear what you mean by type safety in JavaScript. You're not using TypeScript or Flow, right? Then what exactly do you want to make safe?

Comment: I think what you are really looking for is `return [x, y].filter(pred)`.

Comment: @Bergi: No, because I need the both cases either unwrapped and only when both satisfy the predicate in a pair like array.

Comment: @DaFunc Ah, right. Still, I'd then write `unwrapSingleElement([x, y].filter(pred))`, especially since you are not using another `def`ault value.

Comment: @Bergi This is just a simplification of the given code. Your solution makes the operation neither more general nor more reliable. You still rely on the fact that `Array` can represent the lack of a value - and you even implicitly rely on it, which is worse. As soon as the caller isn't able to handle this case or doesn't take it into account, the code will break eventually.

Comment: @Bergi I am more concerned about the type of the predicate, because it seems to require a first class polymorphic type. I am not sure though if higher rank types are applicable here and if this indicates a problem in the first place.

Comment: @reify Yes, this is just a simplification. I do not know how to make it more general or reliable since I don't know what the OP needs this for. I agree however that something like `unwrapSingleElement` which returns either an array or an anything is a bad idea (that's why my first suggestion didn't include it).

Comment: This seems like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It would be helpful if we knew why you want to write code like this. What is the context? What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Asking about type safety in Javascript is a bit delicate, because it is an untyped language. But by considering types anyway you are on the right track to make your code more reliable and more comprehensable.

### Throw Errors Early

As we don't have a compiler that uncovers bugs for us before the application is shipped, the following rule of thumb applies:

*Your code should always throw `Error`s as soon as possible rather than implicitly swallowing them.*

As you already noticed your function can be thought of as an inclusive or type (as opposed to `either` that represents exclusive or). However, since the codomain of `orFun` is not restricted to `Boolean`s, you are in trouble, because there is no general default value for this case. You could yield a unit type like `null`, but than you'd impose the caller to perform `null` checks. Rather be honest and throw:

```
const orFun = p => x => y => {
  const r = p(x),
    s = p(y);

  if (!r && !s)
    throw new TypeError();

  return r && s ? [x, y]
    : r ? x
    : y;
};

const entry = {key: 1, value: "a"},
  none = {};

orFun(x => x !== undefined) (entry.key) (entry.value); // [1, "a"]
orFun(x => x !== undefined) (none.key) (none.value); // throws TypeError
```

### Make Cases Explicit

There is a second more subtle flaw in your code: `opFun` returns three different types:

```
Number
String
[Number, String]
```

You should make this fact explicit. One way to achieve this is to impose the provision of all cases on the caller. I use an encoding of the discriminated union type for this:

```js
// discriminated union helper

const unionType = tag => (f, ...args) =>
   ({["run" + tag]: f, [Symbol.toStringTag]: tag, [Symbol("args")]: args});

// union type

const These = unionType("These");

const _this = x =>
  These((_this, that, these) => _this(x), x);

const that = x =>
  These((_this, that, these) => that(x), x);
  
const these = (x, y) =>
  These((_this, that, these) => these(x, y), x, y);

// orFun

const orFun = p => x => y => {
  const r = p(x),
    s = p(y);

  if (!r && !s)
    throw new TypeError();

  return r && s ? these(x, y)
    : r ? _this(x)
    : that(y);
};

// mock objects

const entry = {key: 1, value: "a"};
const value = {value: "a"};
const key = {key: 1};
const none = {};

// MAIN

const entryCase =
  orFun(x => x !== undefined) (entry.key) (entry.value);
  
const keyCase =
  orFun(x => x !== undefined) (key.key) (key.value);
  
const valueCase =
  orFun(x => x !== undefined) (value.key) (value.value);
  
let errorCase;

try {orFun(x => x !== undefined) (none.key) (none.value)}
catch (e) {errorCase = e}

console.log(
  entryCase.runThese(
    x => x + 1,
    x => x.toUpperCase(),
    (x, y) => [x, y]));
  
console.log(
  keyCase.runThese(
    x => x + 1,
    x => x.toUpperCase(),
    (x, y) => [x, y])),
    
console.log(
  valueCase.runThese(
  x => x + 1,
  x => x.toUpperCase(),
  (x, y) => [x, y]));

console.error(errorCase);
```

Additionally, this style spares you conditional statements on the calling side. You still don't have type safety but your code gets more resilient and your intention becomes clearer.

The technique above is basically pattern matching by continuation passing (CPS). A higher order function closes over some data arguments, takes a bunch of continuations and knows which continuation to pick for a certain case. So if someone tells you there were no pattern matching in Javascript you can prove them wrong.

### A More General Implementation

You asked for a more general implementation. Let's start with the name: I think what you're basically doing here is a *to `These`* operation. You want to construct a `These` value from a source that might not satisfy its type. You could implement such an operator for `Either` (represents logical xor) or `Pair` (represents logical and) as well. So let's call the function `toThese`.

Next you should pass two predicate functions so that you are more flexible in determining the case.

And lastly there might be a sensible default value in some cases, hence we don't always want to throw an error. Here is a possible solution:

```js
const _let = f => f();

const sumType = tag => (f, ...args) =>
   ({["run" + tag]: f, [Symbol.toStringTag]: tag, [Symbol("args")]: args});

const These = sumType("These");

const _this = x =>
  These((_this, that, these) => _this(x), x);

const that = x =>
  These((_this, that, these) => that(x), x);

const these = (x, y) =>
  These((_this, that, these) => these(x, y), x, y);

const toThese = (p, q, def) => x => y =>
  _let((r = p(x), s = q(y)) =>
    r && s ? these(x, y)
      : !r && !s ? def(x) (y)
      : x ? _this(x)
      : that(y));
      
const isDefined = x => x !== undefined;

const o = {key: 1, value: "a"};
const p = {key: 1};
const q = {value: "a"};
const r = {};

const tx = toThese(isDefined, isDefined, x => y => {throw Error()}) (o.key) (o.value),
  ty = toThese(isDefined, isDefined, x => y => {throw Error()}) (p.key) (p.value),
  tz = toThese(isDefined, isDefined, x => y => {throw Error()}) (q.key) (q.value);
  
let err;

try {toThese(isDefined, isDefined, () => () => {throw new Error("type not satisfied")}) (r.key) (r.value)}
catch(e) {err = e}

console.log(tx.runThese(x => x + 1,
  x => x.toUpperCase(),
  (x, y) => [x + 1, y.toUpperCase()]));

console.log(ty.runThese(x => x + 1,
  x => x.toUpperCase(),
  (x, y) => [x + 1, y.toUpperCase()]));

console.log(tz.runThese(x => x + 1,
  x => x.toUpperCase(),
  (x, y) => [x + 1, y.toUpperCase()]));
  
 throw err;
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially the `either` part cleared things up for me. However, I haven't understood the second part of your answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first oddity in terms of a *function* in *functional programming* is the same function may return different types:

- `[String, Number]`
- `String`
- `Number`

The following code is an attemp to encode the problem in a better way using *tagged sums*.

Anyway, *unwrapping* the result might be a design smell, since how would you treat each different output (i.e. *type*) once it gets unwrapped? I've defined that `unwrapObjectKind` to just output the values. In a real world case, you would use a partially-applied `cata` to continue doing specific stuff as an answer to each tag.

```js
// #1 Provide the tagged sum type to encode the cases
const ObjectKind = {
   keyAndValue: x => ({ tag: 'keyAndValue', x }),
   key: x => ({ tag: 'key', x }),
   value: x => ({ tag: 'value', x }),
   none: x => ({ tag: 'none', x })
}

// #2 Encodes the whole cases and tags them
const toObjectKind = x => {
   if (x != null && typeof x == 'object') {
     if (x.hasOwnProperty ('key') && x.hasOwnProperty ('value')) 
         return ObjectKind.keyAndValue ([x.key, x.value])
     else if (x.hasOwnProperty ('key')) 
         return ObjectKind.key (x.key)
     else if (x.hasOwnProperty ('value'))
         return ObjectKind.value (x.value)
   }
         
   return ObjectKind.none ([])
}

// #3 Tag the whole cases
const caseA = toObjectKind ({ key: 'a', value: 1 })
const caseB = toObjectKind ({ key: 'b' })
const caseC = toObjectKind ({ value: 3 })
const caseD = toObjectKind (null)


// #4 Catamorphism in order to match cases and do
// actions accordingly
const cata = matches => ({ tag, x }) => 
      matches[tag] (x)

// The identity combinator, to unwrap the cases
const I = x => x

// #5 Unwraps any of tagged object kinds.
const unwrapObjectKind = cata ({ 
   keyAndValue: I,
   key: I,
   value: I,
   none: I
}) 

const outputA = unwrapObjectKind (caseA)
const outputB = unwrapObjectKind (caseB)
const outputC = unwrapObjectKind (caseC)
const outputD = unwrapObjectKind (caseD)

console.log ('outputA:', outputA)
console.log ('outputB:', outputB)
console.log ('outputC:', outputC)
console.log ('outputD:', outputD)
```

Answer (score 0):

How? -- Self-implement type checking for respective functions.

The type checks may be generalised as follows:

```
const findTypeMismatch = (function() {
  const TypePattern = {
    Date: /Date/,
    Null: /Null/,
    Number: /Number/,
    Object: /Object/,
    RegExp: /RegExp/,
    String: /String/,
    Undefined: /Undefined/
  };

  /**
   * If there's any argument with a type that doesn't match the expected type as described in argumentsMeta, that argument is returned.
   * In the case where there are multiple mismatches, the first mismatch is promptly returned.
   *
   * @param Array.<*> arguments List of arguments 'actually' passed to the function for which the check is being made.
   * @param Array.<{ name: String, type: String }> argumentsMeta A list meta items that describe their corresponding item in the arguments list.
   */
  function findTypeMismatch(arguments, argumentsMeta) {

    return argumentsMeta
      .find(
        (meta, index) => {
          return !TypePattern[meta.type]
            .test(
              Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[index])
            )
        }
      );
  }

  return findTypeMismatch;
})();
```

So that `findTypeMismatch` may be used as exemplified:

```
const orFun = function orFun(x /* should be a number */ , y /* should be a date */ ) {
  if (findTypeMismatch(Array.from(arguments), [{
      name: "x",
      type: "Number"
    }, {
      name: "y",
      type: "Date"
    }])) {
    return new Error("Illegal arguments where found");
  }

  // ...
  // actually valuable function logic implementation
  // ...
};
```

If you prefer to throw, then extend `findTypeMismatch` as below:

```
function assertNoArgumentTypeMismatch() {
  const foundMismatch = findTypeMismatch.apply(null, arguments);

  if (!foundMismatch) {
    return;
  }

  throw new Error(`IllegalArgument: expected parameter ${foundMismatch.name} to be of type ${foundMismatch.type}`);
}
```

Causing an adaptation of `orFun` to the following effect:

```
const orFun = function orFun(x /* should be a number */ , y /* should be a date */ ) {
  assertNoArgumentTypeMismatch(Array.from(arguments), [{
      name: "x",
      type: "Number"
    }, {
      name: "y",
      type: "Date"
    }])

  // ...
  // actually valuable function logic implementation
  // ...
};
```